# How to run Python file from command prompt by selecting anaconda or Python in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, windows-10, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda with Python version 3.x and I have already installed native python 3.6.4. I wanted to run my python script from the command prompt either using anaconda or native python according to my need.

I tried to run Python script from command prompt but it is actually using anaconda's python instead of the native one.

My native python is installed in C:/users/user_name/Appdata/local/programs/python/python36

How should I installed anaconda or what steps can I take.

I didn't set any environment variables. I don't prefer that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should update Python to at least 3.7.

On the first line of your script put this shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This is for Unix but I understand it works for Windows also. For more detail on shebangs, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines).

On Windows, the standard Python installer already associates the .py extension with a file type (Python.File) and gives that file type an open command that runs the interpreter (D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*). This is enough to make scripts executable from the command prompt as foo.py. If you’d rather be able to execute the script by simple typing foo with no extension you need to add .py to the PATHEXT environment variable.

For further reading: [here](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I am able to execute my python file using command prompt(but it is calling conda first). My isuue is how to make it executable either using conda or native python using cmd depending upon my requirement.

Comment: Does it call Conda first if you put the shebang I suggested at the top of your script?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. I tried installing anaconda again without adding it to the path. Now I am able to execute native python from cmd.